# PostgreSQL: Updating column in a table based on another indirectly referenced table

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

After adding a new column `new_column` to an existing table `rules`, I would like to apply some complex migration logic in order to determine the new value for each row (I need to look at another table called `flags` which is indirectly referenced by `rules`).

---

#### My questions:

**Q1.** Can I accomplish this with `JOIN` and a `CASE` statement, or would I need to write a `pgSQL` function?

**Q2.** Which of the logical approaches is better (pseudo code):

---

```
FOR flag IN flags
  FOR app IN applications WHERE app.accountid = flag.accountid
    FOR campaign IN campaigns WHERE campaign.applicationid = app.id
      FOR rule IN rules WHERE rule.campaignid = campaign.id
        SET rule.new_column TO
          (CASE flag.new == true AND flag.old == false THEN ‘v2’
           CASE flag.new == false AND flag.old == true THEN ‘v1’
           ELSE return ‘v0’)
```

Or is it better to go about it this way:

```
FOR rule IN rules
  SELECT campaign FROM campaigns WHERE campaign.id = rule.campaignid
  SELECT app FROM applications WHERE app.id = campaign.applicationid
  SELECT flag FROM flags where flag.accountid = app.accountid
  SET rule.new_column TO
    CASE (flag.new = true AND flag.old = false) THEN 'v2'
    CASE (flag.new = false AND flag.old = true) THEN 'v1'
    ELSE 'v0'
```

---

Example:

```
flags:

accountid | new | old 
---------------------
1         |true |true
2         |true |false

applications:

id | accountid
--------------
3  | 1
4  | 2

campaigns:

id | applicationid
------------------
5  | 3
6  | 4

rules:

campaignid | new_column (wanted result)
----------------------
5          | 'v0'
5          | 'v0'
6          | 'v2'
```

Comment: A1: you can do an update from a JOINed query expression. A2: Both *queries* are syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
update rules 
  set new_column = case 
                     when f.new and not f.old then 'v2'
                     when not f.new and f.old then 'v1'
                     else 'v0'
                   end
from campaigns c
  join applications a on c.applicationid = a.id
  join flags f on a.accountid = f.accountid
where c.id = rules.campaignid;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/JHHP6967

Comment: Thanks. Please have a look at the solution I posted. It seemed to do what I want, but differs in that it doesn't use the `join` keyword. Could you please explain the difference between my solution and yours?

Comment: @AlexGordon: that's essentially the same thing as mine, just using those ancient implicit joins instead of an explicit `JOIN` operator

Answer (score 0):

I think I've achieved what I wanted with JOINed query expression (thanks @joop).

I'll post it here in case it might be useful for others:

```
UPDATE 
    rules AS r 
SET 
    rbversion = 
CASE  
WHEN f.new = TRUE AND f.old = FALSE THEN 'v2'
WHEN f.new = FALSE AND f.old = TRUE THEN 'v1'
ELSE 'v0'
END 
FROM 
    flags AS f,
    campaigns AS c,
    applications AS a
WHERE
    c.id = r.campaignid AND
    a.id = c.applicationid AND
    f.accountid = a.accountid
```